# Should I avoid repack multiple iterables unpacked? e.g. (*(1,2),*(3,4)) to get (1,2,3,4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Is the syntax `(*(1,2),*(3,4))` to get `(1,2,3,4)` is supported as standard so is portable or It's just implementation defined syntax so should avoided?

while using python console of notepad++ plugin, I found both of

```py
bytes((*range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1),*range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1))).decode()
```

and

```py
"".join(map(chr,(*range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1),*range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1))))
```

but these caused same SyntaxError. But I tried this in windows IDLE 3.6.3 shell and ubuntu python 3.6.5 (`$ python3`)and both worked.

So I tried `(*(1,2), *(3,4))` in npp python plugin console and it caused same error in contrast with in IDLE and ubuntu.

Is it just because that npp plugin console doesn't support python well or that syntax isn't standard?

I tried to find information, but I was even unable to get keyword. nobody was talking about syntax repacking unpacked.

Comment: Standard in Python 3.5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.7, it works

```
x = (*(1,2), *(3,4))
```

In python 3.4 it doesn't

```
x = (*(1,2), *(3,4))

  File "main.py", line 1
    x = (*(1,2), *(3,4))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3.5 (I think) introduced these new ways on constructing tuples, dicts etc. through unpacking.

You're probably using 2 different versions of python-3.x in those two environments.

Here's another interesting example with `dict`s. Merge two dicts,

```
d = {**d1, **d2}
```

And here's [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) - which introduced this syntax

Answer (score 0):

1. The code you shared is supported in Python 3.5+, but not in any older version.
2. I wouldn't recommend you use the `*` operator here, it isn't typically used for this kind of usage - more for variadic arguments in function calls. If anything, use an iterator or two, it makes it clearer.

```
result = \
    "".join(chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)) + \
    "".join(chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1))
```

Simplicity and maintainability are very important in real code.

3. Better yet, you can use:

```
import string
result = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
```

Good luck!

Comment: importing that module looks best. Thank you.